# Nautilus toolbar icons became bigger

Tags: 10.10, nautilus, icons

I had installed Mac4Linux from [here](http://www.howtoforge.com/mac4lin_make_linux_look_like_a_mac)
I didnt like it that much so i removed it.
After removing it my nautilus toolbar icons have become large

[image]

Previously it used to look like this with small icons and a path viewer
[image]

How do i get it back?

---

Edit
I realised this is not only happening in nautilus but also in all other apps like rhythmbox, Pinta etc

Edit2
I got the pathfinder thingy

Comment: may be it is because of theme

Comment: @virpara nope it happened only after installing that mac-to-lin thingy. Well i had the same theme before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
Install `dconf-editor` with

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and `dconf-editor`.

go to org > gnome > desktop > applications > interface.

look for `toolbar-style` change it to `both-horiz` may be it is currently `both` in your case.

---

- `both-horiz` = icon and text in horizontal line as it's in your 2nd screenshot
- `icons` = only show icons
- `text` = no icon only text
- `both` = icon and text in a vertical line

Comment: Thanks. Though Dconf didnt work, i tried the same with gconf. Thanks a lot.

Comment: But what does "both-horiz" do anyways?. Also i changed the value above it to "small"

Comment: `both-horiz` = icon and text in horizontal line as it's in your 2nd screenshot

Comment: `icons` = only show icons, `text` = no icon only text, `both` = icon and text in a vertical line